# Looping a multiple div function

Tags: loops, html

I am trying to make a html page with multiple divs that will be shown when certain links are clicked. Here is an example

Home page:
page 1,
page 2

When i click page 1 it goes to..
Page 1:

Page3, Home

when i click home it goes to.. home page:

page 1,page 2

However when i then click page 1 or page 2 nothing happens and it stays on the same div. is there a script to not only show different divs on click but keep the loop going forever?

thanks.

code below

```
var $prehashval = "";
function loop()
{
if (location.hash.slice(1)!=$prehashval)
    hashChanged();

$prehashval = location.hash.slice(1);
setTimeout("loop()");
}
function hashChanged()
{
var $output;
switch (location.hash.slice(1))

 {
     default:
        $output = location.hash.slice(1);
}
}
 loop();
```

Comment: paste your code on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: pls give more details, I assumes  page1 page2 etc are your links and you have corresponding div's for each of them and what you want is to show and hide them Am i right ... if so specify it in your question your question don't delver a clear picture

Comment: @RenjithKN his code is here http://jsfiddle.net/uFf58/

Answer (score 0):

Javascript + HTML5? There's 'hidden' property which you can use to hide/show a tag.
Have look here: [HTML5 Global Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_globalattributes.asp)

Or use JQuery with function hide/show and even hidden property.

Comment: Code is now in question above!

Comment: i have the div function showing and hiding divs ok its when i try to see the divs again that the function stops

Comment: wow, may be it's all about me but I don't see any OnClick, hide/show divs? You do write a HTML page? Or a web application on some platforms?